# Homotopy group realization

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am looking for information related to the following question:

> For which $n \in\mathbb{N}$ can every group $G$ be realized as $\pi_n(X)$ for some space $X$?

I have seen in Hatcher that $n=1$ is one such case. I was wondering whether this result was true for higher $n$ as well. I tried a google search, but I didn't turn up anything, perhaps because I didn't phrase the question in an optimal manner. Is there any information out there related to this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every abelian group $ G $ and $ n \geqslant 2 \; $ there is a space $ X=K(G,n)\;  $ called an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space (see the index of Hatcher's book), such that $ \pi_i(X,x)=0\; $ for $i \ne n \; $ and $\pi_n(X,x) \cong G \; $.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: $n=1$, always; $n>1$, exactly when $G$ is abelian.  This is necessary, since all higher homotopy groups are abelian, and turns out to be sufficient by the following construction.   Present $G=\langle \Gamma,R\rangle$ with (possibly infinite) generating set $\Gamma$ and relations $R$.  Let $X = \bigvee_\Gamma S^n$ and then for each relation $\in R$ glue in an $S^{n+1}$ according to $r$.  The resulting CW-complex has $\pi_nX = G$.

You might be interested in [Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg-MacLane_space) $K(G,n)$.  These are spaces which have $\pi_n(X) = G$ and all other homotopy groups zero.